# Using powershell object to execute scripts

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, jobs, start-job

Powershell version used:  3.0

Hello everyone,

I'm looking to try and create a new Powershell pipeline and execute a script within it, then get the output it produces into an output variable, but I can't get any output produced from within the object (from the executed script).  The whole point of this is so I don't have to manage the $Error object, which I intend to use for error detection.  Here's an example below:

```
$ps = [Powershell]::Create()

$File = ".\Test2.ps1"
$SortedParams = "-Name blah -Key foo"
$RootDirectory = Get-Location
$ExecutionDirectory = "$RootDirectory\Test3"

$ps.AddCommand("Set-Location").AddParameter("Path", "$ExecutionDirectory")
write-host "COMMAND 1: " $ps.Commands.Commands.Item(0).CommandText

$ps.AddScript("$File $SortedParams")
write-host "COMMAND 2: " $ps.Commands.Commands.Item(1).CommandText

$output = $ps.Invoke()

write-host $output
```

I should mention that I'm trying to use the following 3 methods of producing output within the script executed:

- Write-Host
- Write-Output
- Write-Verbose (used $ps.Streams.Verbose to try to get output, but nothing)

Any suggestions or tips you can give is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you feel there's a specific need to do things the way you're doing them, you might want to look into using PowerShell background jobs instead.

Background jobs allow you to run PowerShell commands in a separate PowerShell instance and then collect the output from those jobs into a variable (if that's what you want to do).

Check out the about_Jobs help topic for more information.

Here's a quick example:

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { "Hello World!" }
$ret = Receive-Job $job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob

# value of $ret will be "Hello World!"
```

Comment: Thanks mikekol!  I attempted to use this logic and it seems that what gets returned is the command itself, rather than the output produced from my scripts.

Comment: Can you post your code?  That's not what I would expect to have happened, so seeing the code you're executing will make it easier to understand exactly what's happening.

Comment: Code is as follows:
    `$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { ".\Test2.ps1 -Name "blah" -Key "foo"" }
    $ret = Receive-Job $job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
    
    Write-host "OUTPUT: " $ret`

Due to formatting issues here, I had to take out two of the 'tick marks' near the double quotes.

Comment: There we go.  The reason you're just getting the command back is because it's enclosed in double-quotes, making PowerShell think that you're just placing a string literal into the pipeline.  If you change the scriptblock to be { .\Test2.ps1 -Name "blah" -Key "foo" }, that will get you closer to what you're looking for.  You may also want to supply the fully-qualified path to the script you want to run, since the job may not be running in the same folder that your current PowerShell session is in.

Comment: Great, thanks for that!  That formatting issue fixed up the logic a bit, but when I run this, it still remains in the same directory:
`$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Set-Location "$ExecutionDirectory"; Get-Location }`

Comment: PowerShell jobs run in an entirely different PowerShell session, so no variables that you have set in your current session will be passed through to the background job.  You can pass parameters to your job using the -ArgumentList parameter.

$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Write-Host ("{0}, {1}!" -f $args[0], $args[1]) } -ArgumentList "Hello","world"

Comment: That makes sense, and thanks for being so patient!  PS jobs are foreign territory for me, I should read up more on them.

This looks like it might be a good solution for me, so let me verify this with my code first to verify the output and I'll get back to you shortly!

Comment: Rewrote this logic to fit my needs and it returns the output from my files!  Thank you so much, this design issue was driving me mad!

Answer (score 0):

You can call another script with the Invoke-Expression cmdlet and capture its output using the -OutVariable parameter.  I recommend using the Out-Null so that data doesn't populate to the console twice, feel free to remove that piped command.  Here's an example:

```
Invoke-Expression -Command "c:\EventLog.ps1" -OutVariable $data | Out-Null

Write-Host $data
```

This is the code from the sample script I used in the above example:

```
Param($ComputerName = ".")

Get-EventLog -ComputerName $ComputerName -Log application -EntryType Error | 
    Group-Object -Property source | 
    Sort-Object -Property Count -Descending | 
    Format-Table Count, Name -AutoSize
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Colyn1337!  However, I was intentionally trying to avoid calling my scripts from my current execution pipeline so I wouldn't have to clean up the $Error object, should I choose to manually execute this script.  This is actually a similar implementation that I was using previously.  I will consider using this though if I cannot find a solution to my current implementation!

Comment: Tell me more about what you're trying to accomplish.  I *might* be able to help further :]

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to accomplish 3 things:
 
 - Call a script
 - Execute commands
 - Pass output of commands back to main script for logging

I'm intentionally trying to avoid directly pushing the output to a log file in each script.  I'm trying to collect all output within a single script and _then_ log the output to a log file.

I should also mention that I don't want this to execute from the current pipeline, so I don't have to manage the $Error variable cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

Check your error stream for errors:

```
$ps.Streams.Error
```

This worked for me:

```
$ps = [Powershell]::Create()
cd 'C:\Users\Andy\Documents'
$File = ".\Test2.ps1"
$SortedParams = "-Name blah -Key foo"
$RootDirectory = Get-Location
$ExecutionDirectory = "$RootDirectory\Test3"
$ps.AddCommand("Set-Location").AddParameter("Path", "$ExecutionDirectory") | Out-Null
$ps.AddScript("$File $SortedParams") | Out-Null
$output = $ps.Invoke()
write-host $output
```

This shows my setup:

Show file organization:

```
Command: 

tree.com /F /A $ExecutionDirectory

Output: 

C:\USERS\ANDY\DOCUMENTS\TEST3
    Test2.ps1
```

Show script contents:

```
Command:

cat "$ExecutionDirectory\Test2.ps1"

Output: 

param (
    $Name,
    $Key
)
$Name
$Key
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Invoke-Expression and this is the only solution working for me:

test2.ps

```
Invoke-Expression .\test1.ps1 | Tee-Object -Variable msg | Out-Null
write-host "Return: $msg"</code>
```

And test1.ps:

```
$hola="Testing"
$hola
```

Call:

```
C:\Test>powershell -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -file test2.ps1
Return: Testing
```